# Add to shortlist PHP MYSQL or JQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm really trying to work out the best approach to creating an add to shortlist option on a clients realestate website.

This link http://www.harcourts.com.au/Property/Residential looks good, and to me it appears to be using a table to storre the data, thats when i thought of maybe using the users ip address to store their data for 30days.

But then the problem would be that if 5 computers are on one ISP then they would have the same shortlists.

I then thought jquery would be good but i have not done anything of that sort before.

If anyone could please provide me a simple php mysql or jquery example of adding unique id's to a shortlist cache or cookie or session that would be great.

PS: I have only beginners knowledge so if examples could be posted or linked I will definitely learn it, not just copy and paste and forget. :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cookie with a 30 day expiry which has a randomly generated id that you use to link to rows in your database.

Initialisation:

```
if( !isset( $_COOKIE['listid'] ) )
{
    $listid = md5( time() ); // Should make sure this is unique
    setcookie( 'listid', $listid , time()+60*60*24*30 );
}
else
{
    $listid = $_COOKIE['listid'];   
}
```

Adding an item:

```
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO `table` ( `listid`, `itemid`) VALUES ("' . $listid . '","' . $itemid . '");' );
```

Retrieving items:

```
$q = mysql_query( 'SELECT `itemid` from `table` WHERE `listid` = "' . $listid . '"' );

while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q ) )
{
    $items[] = $r;
}
```

This is a very basic solution, you would need to build on it to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kane, i am going to try that. So does the cookie expire by itself? All i do then is have a cron script checking that table for expired table entries yeh?

Comment: Yep you would want to periodically empty the table of old data, this would mean you would have to store an expiry date in the table as well.

Comment: Thank you kane, just one more question.. how do i initialize the set cookie? is it a link? i have been googling to see how its done but am not getting far.

Comment: Put that 'initialisation' bit at the top of all of the pages you want the shortlist on. If the cookie doesn't exists i.e. this is their first visit, then it will create it. Subsequent calls will just retrieve it. Hope that makes sense.